# Cython C++ templates

Tags: python, c++, templates, cython

I am fairly new to cython, and I was attempting to wrap a templated vector class defined as

```
template < typename T, uint N >   
struct Vector{}
```

and I am having a difficult time learning about how cython uses templates, especially those with an int as an argument. I read in the docs that ints are not yet supported as template parameters. How do I do this properly?

Comment: It might be better to setup a blog if you're keen to document your explorations in programming. Stack Overflow is intended as a Question & Answer site!

Comment: OH ok. Thanks!  I just posted it here because I look here all the time for answers, and I thought it would be great to have an answer :)  I will setup a blog in the future.

Comment: @MattOstlund You are [totally welcome to answer your own questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer). However, if you do then please post it as a question and answer.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this isn't actually a question. It might be possible to rewrite it as a question and answer, or it might be more appropriate for documentation.

Comment: Thank you for the advice. This was my first post on Stack Exchange, and I fixed it as a question and answer.  Forgive my faux pas.

Comment: @MattOstlund That looks better!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found an easy solution!

In a C++ header file, you can just declare a typedef, for example

```
typedef Vector<float,3>; Vector3f;
```

In your cython file you can just declare that and now you can use all the functions and operators within the class.

```
cdef extern from "Vector.h" namespace "ns":
    cdef cppclass Vector3f:
```

Now, I had an additional issue, and that is with "specialized" functions, in my case a specialization for a Vector with 3 params.

```
template<typename T1, typename T2>
inline Vector<T1, 3 >Cross(const Vector <T1, 3 > & v1, const Vector<T2, 3> & v2)
```

To use this in cython, just declare it outside the class, in my case

```
cdef extern from "Vector.h" namespace "ns":

    cdef cppclass Vector3f:

        ...

    Vector3f Cross(Vector3f v1,Vector3f v2)
```

Comment: Thank you :) I did not know that was an option. I am still fairly new to posting and answering here. I have used codeexchange for research a ton though.

Comment: reviving this old post, but what is in between the dots here?

Answer (score 10):

For the curious, the [Cython wiki](https://github.com/cython/cython/wiki/WrappingCPlusPlus#templates) shows how to write a templated class in Cython:

```
cdef extern from "<vector>" namespace "std":
    cdef cppclass vector[T]:
        ...
```

Furthermore, multiple template parameters are defined as a list.
To answer the OP's question, one would use `cdef struct Vector[T, N]`.